# What is the most efficient method to find x contiguous values of y in an array?

Tags: c++, c, performance, algorithm, profiling

Running my app through callgrind revealed that this line dwarfed everything else by a factor of about 10,000. I'm probably going to redesign around it, but it got me wondering; Is there a better way to do it?

Here's what I'm doing at the moment:

```
int i = 1;
while
(
    (
        (*(buffer++) == 0xffffffff && ++i) || 
        (i = 1)
    )
    &&
    i < desiredLength + 1
    &&
    buffer < bufferEnd
);
```

It's looking for the offset of the first chunk of desiredLength 0xffffffff values in a 32 bit unsigned int array.

It's significantly faster than any implementations I could come up with involving an inner loop. But it's still too damn slow.

Comment: One thing that can be optimized is the readability of that line...

Comment: That's better. But does it *need* to be crammed into the `while` test?

Comment: Have you tried using `std::search_n` - `std::search_n(buffer, bufferEnd, desiredLength, 0xffffffff)`? I imagine that under the hood it could (potentially) leverage SIMD.

Comment: You could be twice as fast by using 64-bit integers and do some small corrections after the loop, assuming that the minimum number of contiguous `0xffffffff` is at least 2.

Comment: Couldn't you skip by desiredLength instead of 1, and then search from there instead?  I.e. if desiredLength is 10, and neither buffer[0] nor buffer[10] match, you don't need to look at buffer[3].

Comment: And to take the 64-bit integer idea a step further, you can also use 128-bit SSE.

Comment: @DSM Great point, it seems obvious now... Going to give that a go.

Comment: @Porges Thanks, I wasn't aware of an STL class that did exactly this, I'll give it a go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tagged c++ so I assume you have STL algorithms available:

```
std::search_n(buffer, bufferEnd, desiredLength, 0xffffffff);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd go for the `search_n` suggestion, too, because I'm pretty sure it does this properly. It's actually pretty easy, and it can be sped up basically by a factor of desired_length. unless the target values are really dense in the array.

Here's the idea: if you have `K` consecutive instances of a value starting at position `I`, then it must be the case that position `I + K - 1` contains that value. So you check that first; if it doesn't, then the earliest position which might contain the K consecutive values is `I + K`, so you can restart the algorithm there.

If, on the other hand, you find the value at `I + K - 1`, then you scan backwards until you either reach `I` (in which case you succeeded), or you reach some position `J - 1` which doesn't contain the target value. In the latter case, you know there are target values from `J` to `I + K - 1`, so you now check `J + K - 1`. If that works, you only have to scan backwards to `I + K`. If it doesn't work, you restart the algorithm at `J + K`.

Most of the time, you'll only look at every `K'th` position in the vector. For large `K`, that's a big win.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) from C standard library. Modern compilers shall have very optimized implementations of `memxxx` functions making the most speed out of modern CPUs.

Comment: I don't think memcmp is applicable here.

Comment: @Alastair With predefined lengths - why not, it can be faster than `std::search_n`. Depends on implementation.

Comment: But it doesn't do the same thing as search_n! I think you need to explain further.

Comment: Of course, it shall be used with e.g. `memchr`, something like BigBoss suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought but you're iterating over the int array one at a time right? Think about this, if `*(buffer) != 0xffffffff` and `buffer[desiredLength-1] != 0xffffffff` then you can be sure that there's no point in checking in between so you can just move `buffer` on by `desiredLength` rather than just by 1 which may significantly improve your speed if `desiredLength` is much larger than one. Of course it complicates your function because:

1. If both `*(buffer)` and `buffer[desiredLength-1]` equal `0xffffffff` then you can't assume it's contiguous between them so you'll still need to check that.
2. If `*(buffer)` doesn't equal `0xffffffff` but `buffer[desiredLength-1]` does equal `0xffffffff` then you've got to track to the beginning of the `0xffffffff` sequence.
3. You've got to ensure you don't overrun the buffer when you check `buffer[desiredLength-1]`

A bit more complex but it *may* speed things up. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Take a cookie for exploiting the data property that's being searched for.

Answer (score 1):

If I want to implement this I will do it using `memchr` and `memcmp`:

```
bool found = false;
std::vector<unsigned char> tmp(desiredLength*sizeof(uint32_t), 0xFF);
while( true ) {
    void* p = memchr(bufferStart, 0xFF,
        (bufferEnd-bufferStart-desiredLength) * sizeof(uint32_t));
    if( !p ) break;
    if( !memcmp(p, &tmp[0], desiredLength * sizeof(uint32_t)) ) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also you can use `std::search_n` that may be better optimized than your own code

Comment: `desiredLength` is length in 32-bit ints, not in chars

Answer (score 0):

For when `std::search_n` isn't available:

```
int i = 1;
while
(
    (
        i == 1
        &&
        buffer < bufferEnd
        &&
        (
            (
                *buffer == desired
                &&
                *(buffer + desiredLength - 1) == desired
                &&
                (i = 3)
            )
            ||
            (buffer += desiredLength && (i = 1))
        )
    )
    ||
    (
        i == 2
        &&
        (
            (
                buffer > arr
                &&
                (*(--buffer) == desired)
            )
            ||
            (i = 3)
        )
    )
    ||
    (
        i >= 3
        &&
        buffer < bufferEnd
        &&
        (
            (
                *(buffer++) == desired
                &&
                (i++ || true)
            )
            ||
            (i = 1)
        )
        &&
        (
            i < 3
            ||
            i - 3 < desiredLength + 1
        )
    )
);
buffer -= i - 4;

if (buffer > bufferEnd - (i-3))
    buffer = bufferEnd;
```

Returns identical results only slightly slower than `std:search_n`:

```
buffer = std::search_n(buffer, bufferEnd-1, desiredLength, desired);
if (buffer == bufferEnd-1)
    buffer = bufferEnd;
```